# Call subform macro from main form in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a macro on the SubForm I'd like to call from the MainForm. I found [this reference](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) but I can't get it working. I've tried

```
Call Form("MainForm").Subform_Macro
```

and

```
Call Form!MainForm!Subform_Macro
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Forms!MainForm!SubForm.Form.Subform_Macro` Should do the trick. [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195393.aspx)